# Unable to change log level with setLevel() method

Tags: java, logging

I defined rootLogger

```
{
final static org.apache.log4j.Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
}
```

But when I attempt to change the logging level

```
{
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
}
```

I still see informational messages (I think I should now see only FATAL messages) and when I check the level with getLevel(), I see a null value.

Am I setting the level incorrectly?

Comment: Provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).